# Program is not exiting loop even thought it appears it knows to

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a guessing game where the user inputs the top number and the computer selects a number between 1 and the number that the user input. After the correct number is guessed, it is supposed to leave the do-while it is in and move on to the toString, but does not.

Here is an example:

```
Guessing Game - How many numbers? 10
Enter a number between 1 and 10: 1
Try again.

Enter a number between 1 and 10: 2
Try again.

Enter a number between 1 and 10: 3
Try again.

Enter a number between 1 and 10: 4
Enter a number between 1 and 10:
```

You can see that it doesn't say "Try again," but yet asked for another guess.

Here is my program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GuessingGame
{
    public int upperBound;
    int guesscount = 0;

    public GuessingGame(int stop)
    {
        upperBound = stop;
    }

    public int playGame()
    {
        boolean guesscorrectly = false;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int correctNum = (int) ((Math.random()*upperBound) +1);
        do{
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and " + upperBound + ": ");
            int guess = kb.nextInt();
            if(guess==correctNum){
                guesscount++;
                guesscorrectly = true;
            }
            else{
                guesscount++;
                System.out.println("Try again.\n");
            }
        }while(guesscorrectly!=true);
        return correctNum;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "You correctly guessed " + playGame() + "! It took you " + guesscount + " guesses.";
    }
}
```

And then here is the main

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class GuessRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Guessing Game - How many numbers? ");
        int upperBound = kb.nextInt();
        GuessingGame test = new GuessingGame(upperBound);
        test.playGame();
        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where exactly is your toString method being called?

Comment: @user2677821 It's being called implicitly in `System.out.println(test)`

Comment: @user2677821In the main when I say "System.out.println(test)"

Comment: I would suggest having a line: "kb.close();" before test.playGame(). Make sure you close your Scanners after using them.

Comment: @PerryMonschau I've been learning Java for over a year now and was never taught how to close my scanners but always knew I needed to (but I will admit I never looked it up). I appreciate the help!

Comment: Suggestion: You can simplify `while(guesscorrectly!=true)` to `while(!guesscorrectly)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calling `playGame()` in your `toString()` method. You shouldn't do that or it will start the game over...

Comment: Beat me to it. Yeah the string isn't printed until the second iteration of playGame()

Comment: Ah I was under the impression it would just print what the method had returned. I throughly appreciate the help, however do you know how I can print what was returned?

Comment: @Grant Java doesn't automatically remember a return value. You must assign it to a variable yourself.

Comment: @Grant Create another class level variable and set it to the correct number right before you return. Then use that number in your `toString()`...

Comment: @Grant create another variable similiar to `int guesscount = 0;` maybe `int correctAnswer = 0;` then set `correctAnswer = guesscorrectly` right before you return in the method. Update your `toString()` with `return "You correctly guessed " + correctAnswer + "! It took you " + guesscount + " guesses.";`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the help guys! This was really giving me quite the headache!!

Comment: @Grant no problem!

Comment: @brso05 Or just declare `correctNum` as a member field instead of a local variable.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes either way.

Comment: @brso05 Also, by `correctAnswer = guesscorrectly`, I think you mean `correctAnswer = correctNum`. (`guesscorrectly` is the `boolean` flag.) I think introducing a new variable with a nearly identical name is just confusing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you are correct I did mean `correctNum` apparently he figured that out lol

Answer (score 0):

Note that whenever you do `playGame()` in your code, it will call the `playGame()` method. This means that the method will be executed inside of `toString()`. You have three ways to fix this.

1. Remove the line that calls `test.playGame()` in `main()`. Then move the `System.out.println()` statement from `toString()` to `main()`, changing `playGame()` to `test.playGame()`.
2. Capture the return value of `playGame()` by assigning it to a variable. Then you can printing that variable's value in `main()` rather than overriding `toString()`.
3. Instead of returning a value from `playGame()`, you can create a member field which stores the value. Then `toString()` uses the value of the member field instead of calling `playGame()`.

Comment: i.e. by adding correctNum as an instance variable in GuessingGame and assigning rather than returning it in playGame, and referencing that variable in your toString.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Or assigning the return value to a local variable in `main()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It could be done that way, but self-containing objects is good practice. Main's code is a lot cleaner as it is.

Comment: @brso05 I'm just suggesting several options. They all have their pros and cons.